# load a component every half second

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

In a vuejs app, I have a component that is loaded while waiting for reply from the api.

It contains a simple blurred line (no props or events). I want to load that same component every half second additionnaly, i.e. it starts with one line, half a second later a second line, after another half second the third line and so on.

```
   <TheLoadingLine />
```

TheLoadingLine contains:

```
<template>

  <div class="flex flex-row justify-between md:mb-4 blur-sm ">

    <div class="grow flex flex-col md:flex-row justify-between text-bleulfdm pl-6 pr-4 p-1 mb-1 shadow-md xl:rounded-full shadow-bleutresclair text-sm xl:text-lg">

      <div class="flex flex-row w-full">
        <span class="basis-12 md:basis-24">2 janv</span>
        <span class="md:basis-72 ">intitule</span>
        <span class="inline-block">catégorie</span>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div class="flex flex-row justify-between" >
          <div></div>
          <div class="font-bold lg:font-normal">10€</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>
```

I thought of a function with a setInterval, something like:

```
let timer = setInterval(load_component_function, 500)
```

But I have no real clue of what to put in such a function and how to implement that.

Comment: I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple. To show component in Vue you use `v-if` or `v-show` so you just need a proper condition.

```
<TheLoadingLine v-if="counter > 0" />
<TheLoadingLine v-if="counter > 1" />
<TheLoadingLine v-if="counter > 2" />
```

Just increase a counter by one in a `setInterval` callback

You can also use a `v-for`:

```
<TheLoadingLine v-for="c in counter" :key="c" />
```

Comment: the `v-for` solution is very elegant. Thanks.